# Inside an R function, how do I access the calling environment?

Tags: r, r-environment

```
foo <- function() {
  # how to know what environment_of_caller is
}

caller <- function() {
  # environment_of_caller
  foo()
}
```

A function that I'm writing needs to the know the environment of its caller. Can that be done without passing the environment in as an argument?

Comment: You could use `parent.frame`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you really need to do this, the function `parent.frame()` gives it.

```
foo <- function() {
  parent.frame()$a
}

caller <- function() {
  a <- 1
  foo()
}

caller()
## [1] 1
```

however, normally one would write it like this (only `foo` is changed) as it gives the desired functionality but also the flexibility to change the environment used.

```
foo <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  envir$a
}

caller <- function() {
  a <- 1
  foo()
}

caller()
## [1] 1
```